# Indicate binding source for a model using a custom model binder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, model-binding, swashbuckle

I have create a custom model binder to associate files and additional metadata together. Consequently, this requires that the endpoint accept `multipart/form-data`. As I understand it, this can be hinted by applying the `FromForm` attribute on the parameter.

However, I noticed if I omit the `FromForm` attribute, our swagger documentation isn't able to tell the difference and assumes a json model.

**Is there a way I can annotate the binder provider, binder, or model to indicate it's binding source is the form?**

If I used `IFormFile` for instance, it's automatically assumed to be from the form. I want it to be inferred if my type is used, it will also be assumed to be from the form.  Perhaps this is some Swashbuckle voodoo that I'll have to add?

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload-files")]
public async Task<UploadFilesResult> UploadFiles(
    [FromForm] // how can I make it so this is implied so the attribute isn't needed?
    FileAndMetaModel<FileMeta> files)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// controller
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save([FromForm] CompanyViewModel company, IFormFileCollection files)
{            
    // TODO           
    return Ok();
}

// startup.cs
services.AddControllers(options => {
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new FromFormModelBinderProvider());
});

public class FromFormModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        if (!context.Metadata.ModelType.IsPrimitive &&
            !context.Metadata.ModelType.Equals(typeof(string)) &&
            context.Metadata.BindingSource.Id == "Form") {
            return new FromFormModelBinder();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class FromFormModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        // Fetch the value of the argument by name and set it to the model state
        string fieldName = bindingContext.FieldName;
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(fieldName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None) return Task.CompletedTask;
        else bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(fieldName, valueProviderResult);

        // Do nothing if the value is null or empty
        string value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return Task.CompletedTask;

        try {
            // Deserialize the provided value and set the binding result
            var options = bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>>().Value;
            object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value, bindingContext.ModelType, options.SerializerSettings);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }
        catch (JsonException) {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

[image: postman]